# libvirt and VirtualBox / Getting Started

Tags: api, virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt

I'm trying to get started on libvirt with VirtualBox as a virtualization solution. I installed everything and VirtualBox itself is running when using their VBoxHeadless command.
However, libvirt fails to connect to VirtualBox:

```
# virsh -c vbox:///session
libvir: error : could not connect to vbox:///session
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

I could not find any hints in the libvirt documentation that point to whether I have to make any domain specific configuration before using virsh.

Does anyone have a hint? Or even better, maybe a tutorial that works through the way of using libvirt, virsh or it's APIs (my later goal) from the ground up.

Answer (score 15):

If you are doing this on Ubuntu, then the problem is their [libvirt package is built without VirtualBox support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/667076%5d).

You can rebuild the package with support very easily. Something like:

```
apt-get source -d libvirt
sudo apt-get build-dep libvirt
dpkg-source -x libvirt*dsc
```

Go into the `libvirt` directory and edit `debian/rules` so that instead of `--without-vbox` it says `--with-vbox`. You can add an entry to the top of `debian/changelog` so the package is compiled as a different version (e.g., append ~local1 to the version).

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b -rfakeroot
```

You'll get new .debs built in the directory above. Use `dpkg -i` to install the relevant ones (libvirt0, libvirt0-bin, and whatever else you want).

Answer (score 0):

Double-check whether or not you have write access to `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`.

The socket file should have permissions similar to:

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
srwxrwx--- 1 root libvirtd 0 2010-08-24 14:54 /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

I think it could be helpful also to increase the libvirt logging capabilities by running this in your shell:

```
export LIBVIRT_DEBUG=1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Ubuntu PPA for libvirt with VirtualBox support: https://launchpad.net/~cxl/+archive/ubuntu/libvirt